# Teradata Query for "IF-ELSE"

Tags: if-statement, select, teradata

In MySQL we can write this query. Assuming there's a column field1 & field2 and a table table1.

```
select IF(field1 > 10, true, field2) AS `mycolumn` from table1
```

How can I achieve similar logic with Teradata query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN field1 > 10 THEN 'true' ELSE field2 END AS mycolumn
FROM table1;
```

The above assumes that `field2` be a text column.  If not, then the `'true'` in the `CASE` expression would have to be replaced with a literal matching the type of `field2`.